# how to use playbackRate for changes speed logo video in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have logo video on site and I want to change the speed slow in React,
I tried to use Js Dom : "document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 0.6;"
but it didn't work and gave me an error, I tried putting in the function but the same error.

```
Preloader from "./videos/Preloader.mp4";

 const Videologo= () => {

   const vspeed = () => { 
    const v =document.querySelector('video');
     v.PlaybackRate = 0.6;
      }
    vspeed();
    

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <video autoPlay muted loop >
        <source src={Preloader} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
}
```

img of code

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi ahmed and welcome to SO. Please include the React code that is related to your question and try to be specific about any errors you encounter. When using React one usually steers clear from any DOM selection and works with references to elements instead.

Comment: Please add your code as actual text. Images of code are very hard to work with.

Answer (score 1):

In React you can create a reference to an element with the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. The ref is created after the first render.

So that means that you have to use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook to change the `playbackRate` of the video after the first render has occurred.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Preloader from "./videos/Preloader.mp4";

const Videologo= () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    videoRef.current.playbackRate = 0.6;
  }, []);    

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted loop>
        <source src={Preloader} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Glad to help out. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted to help out others with the same question.